# How to open a tmux terminal with automatically separated to 6 windows?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I can start tmux with simply issuing: "tmux", then by hand, separate the windows to 6:

[image]

But how could I automatically start tmux with "X" amount, ex.: 6 of separated windows? So I could work later on ex.: 6 different machines in parallel. Good stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
tmux new-session \; split-window -h \; split-window -v -p 66 \; split-window -v \; select-pane -t 0 \; split-window -v -p 66 \; split-window -v \;
```

Also, consider looking at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened.

Comment: Does it execute the .bashrc in every panes? in mine it does not.

Comment: @рüффп For me .bashrc is executed at start of each pane.

Comment: You're right, my problem was a .bash_profile who was bypassing the .bashrc. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: This command in shell works:
`tmux new-session \; split-window -h \; split-window -v` 
However, if I use these 3 lines in .tmux.conf,  and type tmux in the shell, it created an two sessions, namely "0" and "1".   Session "0" has the 3 nicely split windows, and session "1" has a single window (no split).  Even worse, it automatically selects session "1".   So, the final result is to show me a single (no split) window..

Answer (score 1):

[The other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412928/213782) is nice and simple. If you want anything more advanced (e.g. save state that includes window names, current directories and running commands and/or if you have more windows/more complicated layouts) there are a couple plugins available. Here's a quick summary.

Using the [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) plugin, put your pane configuration in a yaml file as described by the documentation, then start with

```
tmuxinator start [project] -n [name]
```

Here's a sample yaml file so you get the idea of what it will look like:

```
  - editor:
       layout: b147,208x73,0,0[208x62,0,0,208x10,0,63{104x10,0,63,103x10,105,63}]
       panes:
         - vim
         - #empty, will just run plain bash
         - top
```

There's also the [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) plugin (which I personally use). The nice thing is you can set up a `tmux` session and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (or whatever your prefix key is) followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and your layout will be saved to file. To restore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

With tmux-resurect I don't know offhand how to automate the restore so you can start `tmux` with the layout already loaded (as opposed to starting and then restoring with `Ctrl-R`). I'm guessing it's possible but I'll leave it to you to figure out if you decide to use this plugin.

EDIT: The [Continuum Plugin](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum/) allows for an automated restore immediately after launching tmux